# How to reference System.Windows.Forms from a net462 targeting SDK project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, gac

Is there any possibility of referencing `System.Windows.Forms` from an Sdk project (VS 2017) that targets `net462`? Something like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net462</TargetFrameworks>
    ...    
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.Windows.Forms" Version="4.0.0" />
...
```

Or to generalize the question: how can system libraries residing in the GAC be used from Sdk projects? According to [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/987) it seems it is not something supported out-of-the-box.

The part that confuses me is that targeting `net462` gives the impression that one has access to the *full* framework. However, if GAC assemblies are an issue, the framework is not so "full" anymore. Thus, my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following compiles for me:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            var form = new Form();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: Instead of editing the project file directly, you can add these references the same way you would in a Framework project, by right clicking on Dependencies in the Solution Explorer and choosing Add Reference. Click on Assemblies and then Framework, and select the assemblies you want.